# JavaScript random message when click on button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display a random text when clicking on a button but something is wrong.... Something related to the onload.function?

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="randomMessages.js"></script>
  <title>MakeHappy, One good thought everyday!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MakeHappy.css" />
</head>

<body class="main">
      <button onclick="newTitle()">Make new title</button>
<br />
<span id="target"></span>
</body>
```

/

```
window.onload = function{
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var titles = [
    'Test 1',
    'Test 2',
    'Test 3',
    'Test 4',
    'Test 5'
];

function newTitle () {
    var i = (Math.random() * titles.length) | 0;
    target.innerText = titles[i];
}

newTitle();
}
```

Comment: "but something is wrong" is not a useful problem statement. What do you expect to see? Do you see any errors in the console? Have you done any debugging yourself? --- Hint: you have a syntax error.

Comment: Nothing display when I hit the button, on the debug console: Uncaught ReferenceError: newTitle is not defined

Comment: I'd suggest using an event listener instead of an inline `onclick`.

Comment: move newTitle function outside the onload function

Comment: Remove `newTitle();` at bottom of your code i don't think its required to use

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `()` after `function`, and you've put `newtitle` *inside* your `load` handler, making it non-global, but `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers can only call global functions. (One of the many reasons not to use them.)

Instead, I suggest hooking up the handler with modern event handling:

```
<button id="btn">...</button>
```

and

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Note ------------^^

    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var titles = [
        'Test 1',
        'Test 2',
        'Test 3',
        'Test 4',
        'Test 5'
    ];

    newTitle();

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", newTitle, false);

    function newTitle() {
        var i = (Math.random() * titles.length) | 0;
        target.innerText = titles[i];
    }
};
```

---

Also strongly recommend not using `load` to hook things up, as it happens **very** late in the page load cycle. Just move your `script` tag to *after* the elements it acts on (the very end, just before your closing `</body>` tag, is good):

```
<body class="main">
      <button id="btn">Make new title</button>
<br />
<span id="target"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="randomMessages.js"></script>
</body>
```

...where `randomMessages.js` is:

```
// Scoping function to avoid creating globals
(function() {
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var titles = [
        'Test 1',
        'Test 2',
        'Test 3',
        'Test 4',
        'Test 5'
    ];

    newTitle();

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", newTitle, false);

    function newTitle() {
        var i = (Math.random() * titles.length) | 0;
        target.innerText = titles[i];
    }
})(); // Execute the scoping function
```

Comment: So for you it is better to host the script directly into the Html page?

Comment: @Jullian-lucBarber: No, that was just that I'd lost track of your having used an external file while answering. :-) Where the script tag is has nothing to do with whether it's inline or referencing a separate file. I've fixed it above.